# relationship between infinitely often and almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

To find a relationship between $P($A_n $ i .o)$ and almost convergence we generally use the Borel Cantelli lemma.

But let say $A_n$ = ($X_n \neq $ $Y_n$) where $Y_i= X_i I(|X_i|\leq i)$.

It is given that p( $X_n \neq $ $Y_n $ $i.o$)=$0$.

This implies p( $X_n = $ $Y_n $ $i.o$)=$1$.

My question is  this means that $X_n$ - $Y_n$ $\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0 $  ?

Without proving anything , i think this is correct based on my intuition .

Because p( $X_n = $ $Y_n $ $i.o$)=$1$ means no matter how large the n is , $X_n$  equals to $Y_n$. So is this enough to say that $X_n$ - $Y_n$ $\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0 $ in this example  ?

Comment: Your conclusion is correct but $X_n \overset {a.s.} \to Y_n$ is not an accepted notation in Mathematics. You should write it as $X_n -Y_n\overset {a.s.} \to 0$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. I edited the question.